# Can I safely create a new partition between two others?

Tags: partitioning

I am about to install Ubuntu alongside Windows.
My disc is partitioned like this:

/dev/hda1 - system reserved (windows)

/dev/hda2 - ntfs windows users

unallocated space 100Gb

/dev/hda3 - FAT other data 60Gb

Can I create an extended partition in the space BETWEEN hda 2 and 3? 
Will hda3 be renamed and if so, will that lead to data loss?
Data is backed-up.

Comment: It should be OK... you hopefully will just end up with odd partition numbering then. If you are very worried about it you could move the partition into the unallocated space, and leaving the end unallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Linux usually has no problem with partitions being not in sequence. I am not so sure about how/if Windows will see `hda3`. The safe way would be to use gparted from a live System to move that partition so that is is adjacent to `hda2`.

After that you can create a regular installation.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to create that partition between the others.(More exactly it is no more riskier than creating a partition anywhere on the disk.)

The names of the partitions in your final linux install possibly will be different than what is shown now. (/dev/hda3 might be renamed). But that shouldn't affect your windows or linux installation and won't lead to a data loss